# Finding a string in txt file

Tags: c

Building a C program and could use a helpful hand. Making a data structure, where I can fill in user information, like name, surename, gender etc etc and all goes in to a text file. Everything except one thing is working fine.

part of the main

```
int main()
{
FILE *fp;
struct info
{
  char name[15];
  char surename[15];
  char gender[10];
  char education[15];
 } info;

char education1[50];
```

then goes non important part of the code, until we get to the point where if user so desires he can choose to show only registers with for example bachelors degrees. This is how far I've gotten to make it happen but it does not work. Any ideas?

```
FILE *fp=fopen("info.txt", "a");
  while(fp!=NULL && fgets(education1, sizeof(eductaion1),fp)!=NULL)
  {
                 if(strstr(education1,"bachelors"))
                fprintf(fp, "\n%s %s %s %s",
                sem.name,
                sem.surename,
                sem.gender,
                sem.education,);
                if(fp!=NULL) fclose(fp);   

  }
```

Comment: you're opening file for append, but try to read and write to it, also you're trying to close file in loop

Comment: What is a `surename`?

Comment: If you want to read data from file, why do you try to opening it in append mode instead of reading mode and try to add new data in it by `fprintf()` method? Also you won't be able to retrieve data from your file after reading first line of file since you use `fclose()` method.

Comment: Trying to mix reading and writing to the same file is a very dicey business. If your assignment does not require this for some reason then I recommend against it.

Answer (score 2):

You have opened the file in `append` mode, so there will be nothing to read. Also we don't know the file format, but the assumptions made in your code don't seem to match with writing the structures out to file...

Also:

- `fp` will never become `NULL` once you are in the while loop, so the file will never be closed.
- You are trying to write entire structures to the file inside the loop (as you are reading it)
- What are `education1` and `eductaion1` ? You should probably paste your real code.